# Android AlertDialog in libgdx not reacting to click

Tags: android, libgdx, android-alertdialog

I am trying to show an `AlertDialog` inside a class extending `AndroidApplication` (which is a libgdx-class that extends `Activity`). The code looks as follows

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class Solitaire extends AndroidApplication{

public void alertBoxWonMessage() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Solitaire.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.won_title);
    // set message and positive button
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Total time: " + timeForAlert(time) + "<br>" + "Total Points: " + pointsView.getText().toString()))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    Log.d("Hi", "hi");
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    exit();
                    Solitaire.this.finish();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

The dialog is shown and fine, but there is no animation when clicking the positive button and the code inside `onClick` is not executed. Neither is anything written to the console (I also tried `Gdx.app.log(...)` and `System.out.println(...)` instead of `Log.d(...)`, but nothing), nor the dialog dismissed or the Activity closed.

Moreover it seems to be using a lot of memory (computer gets really slow) and printing the following lines to the console:

```
E/EGL_emulation: tid 5206: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9488e800, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
```

I thought it wasn't a problem, because I found some people with the same problem and they were told, that this was not a problem, but maybe it is.

So, any ideas?

Comment: how and from where you call alertBoxWonMessage() method ?

Comment: Try wrapping all the code in this method in a runnable that you pass to `runOnUiThread()`. (just a guess)

Comment: @Tenfour04: Doing that already

Comment: I added these weird console prints that I got, but at the beginning thought weren't important. See the original question at the end.

Comment: @Isabella Are you using emulator ? Have you tried, running on real device?

Answer (score 2):

you're creating Dialog for Android platform may be by you're using it with interfacing. Why don't you use cross platform dialog creation API for libgdx.

Try [gdx-dialogs](https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-dialogs), It's open source cross platform (Android, iOS, iOS-MOE, Desktop) support for native dialogs. Integration is very easy just put dependency in build.gradle, refresh and use.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it does the same thing (shows up, but doesn't respond to clicks). Concerning your comment: It is called inside a runOnUiThread.

Comment: @Isabella please show me calling part of your alertBoxWonMessage() method.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was that the `runOnUiThread` calling `alertBoxWonMessage` was called multiple times. After assuring that it is called only once, everything works fine!

Thank you all for helping.